# Is the reference point (x, y) above or below the non-linear equation?

Tags: coordinate-systems, regression, nonlinear-system, regression-analysis

**BACKGROUND**

In short, I have a series of 3 to 10 data points that will be used to represent a curve.  For example:

- $X=0, Y=10$
- $X=4, Y=7$
- $X=9, Y=12$
- $X=16, Y=10$

**What I am trying to do is determine whether or not a reference point is above or below the curve.**

My gut feeling is that for people in the know, this is a relatively straight forward problem to solve.  Unfortunately, my area of expertise is programming... not mathematics :(

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

If it helps, I have access to the [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to create a curve that passes through the points {(0,0),(4,7),(9,12),(16,10)}. This is called interpolation. This website might help in implementing it using math.net: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Information from the graph you arrive at using interpolation is not reliable beyond the points you did the interpolation with.

Answer (score 1):

Fit a spline to the data points:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29)

http://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/CubicSplines.aspx